# What's the most efficient way to create an alert queue for a model with hundreds of millions of entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alert, bigdata

I am currently working on an application in Rails (though language/framework shouldn't matter for this question since it is more of a theoretical one). I'm working on wrapping my head around this problem:

Say I am tracking millions of blogs online and am plugged into their RSS feeds. My app pings these feeds every few few minutes to see if there has been any new activity across any of these millions of blogs. If there is any new activity, I want to alert users of my application who have signed up to receive alerts for specific blogs that there has been an alert.

Does it make sense to have a user_blog_alerts table (where a user can specify custom keywords to be alerted about) and continuously check this table against every new entry that comes in from my feed? And when there is a match, to add them to a queue (using Redis)?

What is the best, most efficient way to build and model this alerting system? Am I even thinking about this in the right way? Are there any good examples or tutorials on this when working with such large amounts of data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the right way to do this is, but the thought of continuously scanning a table over and over sounds exhausting (ie. unscalable).

Off the top of my head, what if you created a LIST for every blog in Redis.  The values would be the user IDs of those who wanted an alert.  The key name would contain the blog id (ex: "user_blog_alerts:12345").

Then when you got a new post for blog 12345 it's a simple lookup to see if that key exists.  If it does, then fire off alerts for each user in the list.